# Service Stack Vue SPA Application

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, servicestack

I have created a simple project by using the Service Stack Vue SPA template. I run the app by pressing F5, it works fine.

I am trying to find the way to make it working with **app** and **web** tools.

I tried this "**app MyApp.dll**" and it opens the app but blank and with "**web MyApp.dll**" it throws null reference exception.

Can you please help me get it working.

Regards,
Jamil

Answer (score 0):

The `web` [dotnet tool](https://docs.servicestack.net/dotnet-tool) is only for .NET Core 2.1 Apps for .NET Core 3.1+ Apps you should use the new `x` dotnet tool:

```
$ dotnet tool install --global x
```

Please note only the `app` tool supports running in a [.NET Core Windows Desktop App](https://docs.servicestack.net/netcore-windows-desktop), for Console Apps just run the binary with the `dotnet` tool directly:

```
$ dotnet MyApp.dll
```

I followed your description and created a new [vue-spa](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/vue-spa) project:

```
$ x new vue-spa VueSpa
```

Then after publishing the App:

```
$ cd VueSpa\VueSpa
$ npm run publish
```

I can run the published binary with:

```
$ cd bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish
$ app VueSpa.dll
```

Which runs it in a Windows Desktop App as expected:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! @mythz. I following your steps and the app works fine. But how about the "x" or "web"? I tried the "x VueSpa.dll" and the same null reference error is there.

Comment: @Jamil It's not supported in x and web dotnet tools which are "x-plat console dotnet tools", i.e. not UI Desktop Apps. If you just want to run your App as a console app use .NET Core's `dotnet` tool  directly as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I am sorry I think I am confused here. Let me explain. We have started with SharpApp and in that, we have the capability that when you publish it, you can run it with the "app" tool and with "x" tool as well. But now we need to integrate the Vue CLI and since SharpApp does not support the Vue CLI, so I created the VueSpa template assuming that "app" and "x" are dotnet core tool and this VueSpa is using .net code, that's why I am trying to get it working that way. Please suggest.

Comment: @Jamil [vue-spa](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/vue-spa) is not a [Sharp App](https://sharpscript.net/docs/sharp-apps) only Sharp Apps are Sharp Apps, they're completely different, e.g. they are not built, there is no entry point .dll like `MyApp.dll`, they can only be run with the x or app dotnet tools.

Comment: Ok, Thanks! @mythz. I tried "dotnet VueSpa.dll", I can see it host and allow me to run the URL "http://localhost:5000" in the browser. When I try to run that URL in the browser it shows 404. Any configuration required?

Comment: @Jamil The 2 URLs vue-spa is run on is `http://localhost:5000` and `https://localhost:5001`, I've just tested both, they both work.